# Timer Task giving errors in java

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I am making a simple game in java and in it i want to time how long the user takes to guess the number but it is telling me this : local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final.Thanks in advance...

Here is the code to the game

```
    //Creating the random number with the user initialized random class
    Random rand = new Random();
    int  n = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;

    //Variables are declared
    int lives = 10; 
    int secondsPassed = 0;

    //The JOptionPane (Pop-up window) is intitialized
    JOptionPane j = new JOptionPane(JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
        public void run(){
            secondsPassed++;
        }
    };

    while (true){

    int num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(j,"I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20. You have " + lives + " lives. Can you guess it?","EasyMode Singleplayer",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,1000,1000);

    //Here the program decides if the user has lost the game or if he still has lives left        
    if(lives == 0){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(j,"You have lost the game!","EasyMode singleplayer",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0);

    }else if(lives > 0){                
        //The program checks to see if the number is Higher/Lower or equal to the random number generated        
        if(num == n){

            String options[] = {"Yes","No"};
            timer.cancel();
            timer.purge();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(j,"You are correct ! You finished the game with " + lives + " lives!" );
            int saving = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(j,"Do you want to save your score?","Save",JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options,options[1]);
            //Here the program asks the player if he wants to save his lives to his home directory
            if(saving == 0){                            
              try{
                String userHomeFolder = System.getProperty("user.home");
                File file = new File(userHomeFolder,"Scores.txt");
                file.createNewFile();
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

                writer.write("You finished EASYMODE with " + lives + " lives out of 10 lives on Guess The Number!");
                writer.write("It only took you " + secondsPassed);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                //bar.add(panel);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(j,"File successfully saved to your home directory!","File Saved",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                System.exit(0);

              }catch(IOException e){
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
             }else{
                System.exit(0);
             }
```

Comment: Try using `final AtomicInteger secondsPassed = new AtomicInteger()` and `secondsPassed.getAndIncrement()`.

Comment: I think the name timer is confusing when the timer is used as a "scheduler" and I don't normally use it for these use cases to measure elapsed time. I personally prefer using a dedicated library like Google Guava and their stopwatch or even just the old fashion way by keeping track of the start time and end time and making the difference of the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is important that you use a Timer with a TimerTask but if not you could just measure the time at the start and at the end:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
...

long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
...

long secondsPassed = (end - start) / 1000;
```